# Taking in user input whilst encapsulating in Java

Tags: java, input, encapsulation

What I have so far are two classes, Movie class and MovieTestDrive class. I've to get the title, genre and ratings for movies and then put them into an array and call the playIt() method.
When I try to run the code, it won't work and I don't know if this is because I have Scanner running incorrectly whilst encapsulating my data. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

What I have so far:

**Movie class**

```
    // Create instance variables for the Movie class.
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private int rating;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
        title = newTitle;
    }

    public void setGenre(String newGenre) {
        genre = newGenre;
    }

    public void setRating(int newRating) {
        rating = newRating;
    }

    void playIt() {
        System.out.println(getTitle + "- Now Playing!");
    }
```

**MovieTestDrive class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner.input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Create an instance of the Movie class.
    Movie one = new Movie();

    // Take in user input and assign input to the variables for Movie 1.
    System.out.println("Please enter the title of Movie 1");
    one.setTitle = input.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the genre of Movie 1");
    one.setGenre = input.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the rating of Movie 1");
    one.setRating = input.nextInt();

    // Create the second instance of the Movie class.
    Movie two = new Movie();

    // Take in user input and assign input to the variables for Movie 2.
    System.out.println("Please enter the title of Movie 2");
    two.setTitle = input.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the genre of Movie 2");
    two.setGenre = input.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the rating of Movie 2");
    two.setRating = input.nextInt();

    // Create the last instance of the Movie class.
    Movie three = new Movie();

    // Take in user input and assign input to the variables for Movie 2.
    System.out.println("Please enter the title of Movie 3");
    three.setTitle = input.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the genre of Movie 3");
    three.setGenre = input.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter the rating of Movie 3");
    three.setRating = input.nextInt();

    // Print the information.
    System.out.println("Movie 1 Title: " + one.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Move 1 Genre: " + one.getGenre());
    System.out.println("Movie 1 Rating: " + one.getRating());
    System.out.println("");
    // Call the playIt() method for each movie.
    one.playIt();

    System.out.println("Movie 2 Title: " + two.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Move 2 Genre: " + two.getGenre());
    System.out.println("Movie 2 Rating: " + two.getRating());
    System.out.println("");
    two.playIt();

    System.out.println("Movie 3 Title: " + three.getTitle());
    System.out.println("Move 3 Genre: " + three.getGenre());
    System.out.println("Movie 3 Rating: " + three.getRating());
    System.out.println("");
    three.playIt();
}
```

Comment: Can you give more detail on what specifically does not work? What did you expect to happen and what did happen?

Comment: When I try to run it, I get this message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class java.util.Scanner
 at MovieTestDrive1.main(MovieTestDrive1.java:8)" What I expect to happen is for the program to ask the user to input the data and then have that data assigned to the instance variables and then return the information they inputted.

Comment: OK, there are many compile errors there that you'll need to sort out.  Most but not all of them are mentioned in ryan's answer.  There's at least two more. (1) The `playIt()` method needs `()` after `getTitle`. (2) The `next()` method of a `Scanner` generally only fetches one word, so this program won't work if a movie title or movie genre has more than one word; and most movie titles have several words.  I'd also like to pass on one style guideline - if you find yourself repeating the same logic or the same code over and over, it usually means there's a better way to design things. ...

Comment: ...   In this particular case, you could use a couple of loops within `main` - one to input all the details of each movie in turn, and one to print out all the details of each movie in turn.  So you'll have an index variable that goes from 1 to 3, you'll have prompts like `System.out.println("Please enter the title of Movie " + index);`, and you'll store the `Movie` objects in some kind of array.

Answer (score 0):

It should be Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

Also when you set the movie title, it should be one.setRating(input.nextInt()); instead of one.setRating = input.nextInt();

if you type out one.setRating you will see that the method setRating(int NewRating) takes in an int as a parameter, meaning you have to pass in an int (input.nextInt()) when you call this method.